# Cmd line tool to scan an eml file against spam/phishing rules

Tags: linux, email, phishing, spam

For a purpose of a security class I want to demonstrate a threat delivered via email. As a demo message I want to use an eml file that contains a banking-themed pdf attachment, requiring further actions from the user. I want to scan the eml file with a security tool indicating in particular how important it is to have these kind of checks, how output can be logged etc. I know there are plenty of commercial tools out there that provides this end-to-end email security however I want to get as granular as I can so students can visualize the problem better rather than understanding there is a black-box solution that does "the entire security".

What would be a Linux tool that is capable of recognizing threats in eml files? Both from an email perspective (poor grammar, SPF checks, wording, calling to action - buliding spam scoring) as well as link/attachment perspective?

I was thinking about spamassassin however scanning a first random eml (that has a lot of hits on VirusTotal) gives me spam score of 1.3 while 5.0 is the default threshold. Is spamassassin still maintained? Is there any updated rules repository I can use?

Comment: You mean, anti-virus?

Comment: It looks like you are asking for a free, offline, spam analyzer that runs in Linux. Product recommendations are off-topic here,

Comment: There is a reason why you're having trouble finding what you want: this functionality tends to be rolled into commercial products that do a lot more than just this one thing. There's not a lot of point in just scanning for a bayesian analysis of the text. In practice, you want to have multiple analyses going at once.

Comment: Yes, SpamAssassin is still actively maintained. You likely need to configure it. Check to ensure you're querying DNSBLs, URIBLs, and train your Bayesian database.